# Cumulative sum in pandas starting with a zero and ending with the sum of all but the last entry respecting groups

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, cumsum

In the dataframe below, I want to create a new column `C` which will be the *cumulative sum* of `B` for each group in the `A` column, but these sums must start at zero and only add the values until the penultimate entry for that group.

```
  A B
0 1 5
1 1 6
2 2 3
3 2 4
4 2 5
5 3 2
5 3 7
6 4 3
```

So, my result should be:

```
  A B C
0 1 5 0
1 1 6 5
2 2 3 0
3 2 4 3
4 2 5 7
5 3 2 0
5 3 7 2
6 4 3 0
```

(I think this question is really obvious but somehow I couldn't figure it out myself nor I could see it anywhere asked already.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option is to use [`.groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) twice, as follows:

Take the [`DataFrameGroupBy.shift()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift.html) value of `B` under `A` so that for each group of `A`, the first entry of `B` will be reset and become `NaN` for later [`.fillna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) to `0`.

Further grouped by `A` for [`GroupBy.cumsum()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumsum.html) within the local sequence of `A` to get the desired output:

```
df['C'] = (df.groupby('A')['B'].shift()
             .groupby(df['A']).cumsum()
             .fillna(0, downcast='infer')
          )
```

This solution is **vectorized** as well as **supporting non-contiguous groups** too!

**Result:**

```
print(df)


   A  B  C
0  1  5  0
1  1  6  5
2  2  3  0
3  2  4  3
4  2  5  7
5  3  2  0
5  3  7  2
6  4  3  0
```

### Edit

If you are to groupby more than one column and you got "KeyError", check whether your syntax is correctly entered, for example:

If you groupby 2 columns `year` and `income`, you can use:

```
df['C'] = (df.groupby(['year', 'income'])['B'].shift()
             .groupby([df['year'], df['income']]).cumsum()
             .fillna(0, downcast='infer')
          )
```

Pandas supports both syntax with or without quoting `df` passing parameter to `.groupby()`. However, for any `groupby()` that the entity being grouped is not `df` itself, we may not be able to use the abbreviated form to quote just the column labels only e.g. `'year'`, we need to use the full column name e.g. `df['year']` instead.

Comment: I didn't downvoe but this solution does not run on my computer. It throws me a "KeyError" Traceback.

Comment: @WillM.  It shows which key in error ?   I run it without problem.  So weird

Comment: Yeah, it may work in the toy example I wrote (the minimal reproducible example) but I actually am grouping from two colums (year and income) and the double groupby throws errors.

Thank you for your response, this seems the best for grouping with a single column, but Andrej's seems to be the most generalisable (if at the cost of performance).

Comment: @WillM.  That's fine your actual data have different settings.  Actually, all answers here are very well written.  :-)

Comment: @WillM.   For the case you need to groupby for 2 columns or more, you can use the syntax as follows:  for the first `groupby()`,  you can use e.g.  `.groupby(['year', 'income'])` for the second  `groupby()`,  you can use e.g.  `groupby([df['year'], df['income']])`   Pandas supports both syntax with or without quoting `df`.  However, for any groupby() that the entity being grouped is not `df` itself, we cannot use the abbreviated form to quote the column labels only, we need to use the full column name e.g. `df['year']` instead.

Comment: @WillM.  Edited to add the syntax for groupby 2 columns at the second time.  You can take a look no matter you use the solution or not.  :-)

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```py
df["C"] = df.groupby("A")["B"].transform(
    lambda x: x.shift().fillna(0).cumsum().astype(int)
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   A  B  C
0  1  5  0
1  1  6  5
2  2  3  0
3  2  4  3
4  2  5  7
5  3  2  0
5  3  7  2
6  4  3  0
```

Comment: fillna with downcast will also work: `df.groupby("A")["B"].transform( lambda x: x.shift().fillna(0,downcast='infer').cumsum())`

Comment: This solution is both simple and clean, however, coming from an `R` background, I have always believed that what can be done vectorised should be done vectorised. I don't know how python tackled the non vectorisation but `R` is just slow. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Given your groups are already consecutive you can `shift` and use `where` to `NaN` the rows that cross groups. The shift also ensures the cumsum is with respect to previous rows and stats at 0, as you want. Then use the built-in `groupby` + `cumsum` to avoid the slower `lambda`.

```
s = df['A'].shift()

df['C'] = (df.shift()
             .where(df['A'].eq(s))
             .groupby('A')['B'].cumsum()
             .fillna(0, downcast='infer'))


#   A  B  C
#0  1  5  0
#1  1  6  5
#2  2  3  0
#3  2  4  3
#4  2  5  7
#5  3  2  0
#5  3  7  2
#6  4  3  0
```

---

If it turns out that the grouping rows aren't consecutive we can handle this too. The only small modification is that we need to stable sort based on the grouping columns (such that the order within group is preserved and the `cumsum` is correct) and then in the end we can sort the index to get back to the original ordering of the DataFrame, if that's important.

```
# Create DataFrame with non-consecutive groups, 
df = pd.concat([df[::2], df[1::2]], ignore_index=True)
#   A  B
#0  1  5
#1  2  3
#2  2  5
#3  3  7
#4  1  6
#5  2  4
#6  3  2
#7  4  3

df = df.sort_values('A', kind='mergesort')

s = df['A'].shift()

df['C'] = (df.shift()
             .where(df['A'].eq(s))
             .groupby('A')['B'].cumsum()
             .fillna(0, downcast='infer'))

df = df.sort_index()
#   A  B  C
#0  1  5  0
#1  2  3  0
#2  2  5  3  <- Previous row `1` has value 3
#3  3  7  0
#4  1  6  5  <- Previous row `0` has value 5
#5  2  4  8  <- Previous rows `1` and `2` has values 3 + 5 = 8
#6  3  2  7  <- Previous row `3` has value 7 
#7  4  3  0
```

Comment: I really like this vectorised approach coming from `R` mostly. Unfortunately, in my real data set, the groups are not consecutive, they are different level of income in different years (they come cyclically if that helps).